# How to make a code triggers onchange in google app script geocode distance

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a script code to determine the distance between the origin and destination addresses, how do I add a trigger code to automatically fill in the distance column, can anyone help me? here is the code

```
function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type) {
  
  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();
  
  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];
  
  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];
  
  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to minutes and return
        return duration / 60;
      break;
    case "hours":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to hours and return
        return duration / 60 / 60;
      break;      
    case "kilometers":
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }
  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `a trigger code to automatically fill in the distance column`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: What sort of change are you wishing to trigger this function on?

Comment: how to make this code can use with trigger onChange, what code to add and where to put it, can you help me to change this code so that it can use trigger onChange @Tanaike

Comment: About your message of `how to make this code can use with trigger onChange, what code to add and where to put it, can you help me to change this code so that it can use trigger onChange @Tanaike`, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand what you want to do. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

#### Filling in column D with result of function GOOGLEMAPS

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if (sh.getName() == "Geocode Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == 'TRUE') {
    let a = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 3).getValues().flat();
    if (a[0] && a[1] && a[2]) {
      e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(GOOGLEMAPS(a[0], a[1], a[2]));
    }
  }
}
```

Click on check box to fill in distance column

Geocode Sheet:

[image]

Comment: how do I implement it, I want it to be automatic when a row is filled or changed @Cooper

Comment: onEdit only fires when a user performs the edit.  There are no script trigger that fire for other scripts or formulas